# How do I import modules from virtual servers? - Task: Does file exist

Tags: python, windows-7

I am new to Python, currently my task is to write a script to see if a file exists within my corporate FTP location. - Full Win7 environment.

```
import os
if os.path.exists("\\servername\d:\corp\file"):
    print ("yes")
else: 
    print ("no")
```

Does there need to be a .py file located in the file structure on the remote server too for this to be acknowledged in my shell script?

Comment: Why should there be a need for a .py file on the remote server? Does your script not work properly? If so post complete traceback or if it throws no error expected output and real output and how they differ.

Comment: If the file exists, you need to copy it to somewhere in your python path, then import it as a module (no .py extension)